# How to threshold an image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a binary image in OpenCV representing a mask. This mask has some level of geometric noise I want to smooth out, so for this effect I use blurring.

Now I have a grayscale image. I want to take all pixels above a certain threshold and make them white and all other pixels must become black.

Is there an easy way to do this in opencv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
ret,thresh1 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
```

I got from [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

On C++, we have

```
threshold( src_gray, dst, threshold_value, max_BINARY_value,threshold_type );
```

[Here if you want further information](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)

Full code from the last link (C++ tutorial)

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

/// Global variables

int threshold_value = 0;
int threshold_type = 3;;
int const max_value = 255;
int const max_type = 4;
int const max_BINARY_value = 255;

Mat src, src_gray, dst;
char* window_name = "Threshold Demo";

char* trackbar_type = "Type: \n 0: Binary \n 1: Binary Inverted \n 2: Truncate \n 3: To Zero \n 4: To Zero Inverted";
char* trackbar_value = "Value";

/// Function headers
void Threshold_Demo( int, void* );

/**
 * @function main
 */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load an image
  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  /// Convert the image to Gray
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

  /// Create a window to display results
  namedWindow( window_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  /// Create Trackbar to choose type of Threshold
  createTrackbar( trackbar_type,
                  window_name, &threshold_type,
                  max_type, Threshold_Demo );

  createTrackbar( trackbar_value,
                  window_name, &threshold_value,
                  max_value, Threshold_Demo );

  /// Call the function to initialize
  Threshold_Demo( 0, 0 );

  /// Wait until user finishes program
  while(true)
  {
    int c;
    c = waitKey( 20 );
    if( (char)c == 27 )
      { break; }
   }

}


/**
 * @function Threshold_Demo
 */
void Threshold_Demo( int, void* )
{
  /* 0: Binary
     1: Binary Inverted
     2: Threshold Truncated
     3: Threshold to Zero
     4: Threshold to Zero Inverted
   */

  threshold( src_gray, dst, threshold_value, max_BINARY_value,threshold_type );

  imshow( window_name, dst );
}
```